# From hourly data to daily data using SQL GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
fld_id          fld_DateTime                 fld_Index
            2017-07-01 00:00:00.000             5
            2017-07-01 01:00:00.000             10
            2017-07-01 02:00:00.000             15
            2017-07-01 03:00:00.000             40
              ...........
              ...........
            2017-07-01 23:00:00.000             70
            2017-07-02 00:00:00.000             110
            2017-07-02 01:00:00.000             140
            2017-07-02 02:00:00.000             190
              ...............
              ...............
            2017-07-02 23:00:00.000             190
```

What I am trying to do is to group them and count sum of fld_index per day like so:

```
  fld_id          fld_DateTime                    SUM
                  2017-07-01                      190
                  2017-07-02                      400
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
   SELECT fld_dateTime, SUM(fld_Index) AS Sum
FROM tbl_data
WHERE
    AND fld_ConsDateTime BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-08-02'
GROUP BY fld_dateTime
```

It calculates the sum but still in hourly format. How to achieve the daily format like above example?

**UPDATE** Monthly Part Output

```
2017    8   30630800.0000
2017    7   589076201.1800
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database types.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply cast as DATE

```
SELECT CAST(fld_dateTime AS DATE) AS  fld_Date, SUM(fld_Index) AS Sum
FROM tbl_data
WHERE
   fld_ConsDateTime BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-08-02'
GROUP BY CAST(fld_dateTime AS DATE);
```

**EDIT:**

> What about month? Is it the same logic?

It depends on your RDBMS, but in SQL Server you could use:

```
SELECT YEAR(fld_dateTime), MONTH(fld_dateTime), SUM(fld_Index) AS Sum
FROM tbl_data
GROUP BY YEAR(fld_dateTime), MONTH(fld_dateTime);
```

It is important to add year part to avoid grouping records from different years.

Comment: I'd do the CAST part in a derived table, to be fully ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: What about month? Is it the same logic?

Comment: @FreshPro The logic is the same, use function to extract `YEAR` and `MONTH` part in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` part.

Comment: @FreshPro Done.

Comment: @lad2025 I've added the monthly output. Something seems wrong? Can you check question update? There's just two months but 8 records

Comment: @lad2025 sorry that was my bad, not including date filter in where condition

Answer (score 3):

You need to extract the date.  In SQL Server, you would do:

```
 SELECT CAST(fld_dateTime as DATE) as fld_date, SUM(fld_Index) AS Sum
 FROM tbl_data
 WHERE fld_ConsDateTime >= '2017-07-01' AND
       fld_ConsDateTime < '2017-08-03'
 GROUP BY CAST(fld_dateTime as DATE)
 ORDER BY fld_date
```

In MySQL, the above would work, but I would do:

```
 SELECT DATE(fld_dateTime) as fld_date, SUM(fld_Index) AS Sum
 FROM tbl_data
 WHERE fld_ConsDateTime >= '2017-07-01' AND
       fld_ConsDateTime < '2017-08-03'
 GROUP BY DATE(fld_dateTime)
 ORDER BY fld_date;
```

In both cases, you should change the `WHERE` clause.  Your version would keep flights where the date/time is exactly midnight on 2017-08-02.  Using `>=` and `<` is more accurate -- taking all date/times on one day but not the next.